# How to create command aliases in shell?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How to create command aliases in linux?
For example, I'd like to make alias for `ssh root@host`

Thank you?

Comment: As another option you may want to man ssh_config and consider creating a .ssh/config.  Using this file you can set default login users for particular hosts.  For example if you have a lot of switches that use an 'admin' user, you might add an entry for those so you can just ssh switch1 without having to remember 'admin@'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which shell?

Assuming bash, put this kind of thing in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias srhost="ssh root@host"
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to create a .bash_aliases file for portability between my systems I use.
add this to your .bashrc

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

you can then add aliases to this file such as

`alias psg='ps -auxww|grep'`

also after adding a alias you will need to exit/open your terminal so the changes will take affect.

OR try

`source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Only for your user, edit your .bashrc

> alias srhost="ssh root@host"

To add Alias

> alias newcommand="yourcommand -arguments"

To remove Alias

> unalias newcommand